# Delete the same line in multiple VI windows

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I love using vim and vimdiff. I am currently working on comparing two files in vimdiff and I frequently run into the situation that I want to delete the same line in both buffers. In the following example I would like to delete lines 40 and 41.

```
39 text_a  |   39 text_b
40 text_aa |   40 text_aa
41 text_bb |   41 text_bb
42 text_c  |   42 text_d
```

It feels tedious to perform `dd` `Ctrl-W-W`, `dd` `Ctrl-W-W` to delete the line in the current window, jump to the other window, delete the line there and jump back to my original window.

Does anyone know a shortcut for this?

Comment: `:bufdo 40,41d` deletes lines 40 and 41 in all buffers

Comment: hm, that didn't work on my side. does vimdiff split into buffers or windows? maybe thats the problem...

Comment: yep, that was the problem. :windo 40,41p does the trick. @LievenKeersmaekers If you would post your comment as an answer, I could accept it ;)

Comment: done though I'm not sure about the difference for your case...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `bufdo` to delete lines 40 and 41 in all buffers

```
:bufdo 40,41d
```

as per your case using vimdiff, the command is

```
:windo 40,41d
```